# Cannot change branch through code

Tags: acumatica

I have a process whereby I want to change company AND branch when creating a new Journal Entry record.  I have the following code to change branch, which I've obtained from Ruslan:

```
jegraph.FieldDefaulting.AddHandler<Batch.branchID>((s, e) =>
{
    .NewValue = tgtbranch.BranchID;  //Set to ID = 6...
    .Cancel = true;
});
```

However, when checking the value of the branch (for troubleshooting purposes), the branch I come up with is incorrect.  In order to check the branch I'm currently in, I'm using:

```
jegraph.Accessinfo.BranchID;
```

So, either my branch change code is not working, or the AccessInfo method is giving me the wrong information.

Is this the best way to change the branch for a new batch record, or am I not getting the correct info from AccessInfo?

Comment: I am guessing your first example in setting the new value is the value of the record  and the access info shows which branch you are currently logged into which might be different. Is the data for the record you are trying to insert correct? or this is more of a question why these are different?

Comment: The value I'm obtaining from AccessInfo SHOULD be the same as what I had just set it to, I'm thinking...  That's what has me confused.

Comment: I would assume different as one is what you are logged into and the other is what you set on the record. For example in a single transaction you can set different branches - but this doesn't change the default branch you are logged into (accessinfo). See here: https://i.imgur.com/0DITvxo.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The branch info from AccessInfo was incorrect.  The original AddHandler event handler code is working as expected.